# Does App Framework have connection to JQMobi?

Tags: jquery-plugins, frameworks, hybrid-mobile-app

I'm a bit curious as to why there is no official site for JQMobi. As of now, it seems like the only place where I can download JQMobi is through github. And every time I search for JQMobi on Google, Intel's APP Framework shows up.

Is there some kind of connection between JQMobi and Intel's APP Framework? Are they the same or is JQMobi not supported anymore?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`jqMobi` was renamed to [Intel App Framework](http://app-framework-software.intel.com/).

Intel acquired `AppMobi` in 2013, the company that was maintaining `jqMobi` framework, it is now called `Intel App Framework`.